# Is there simpler way of finding objects within parent objects on Roblox (Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local colorwheel = script.Parent
local clickdetector = colorwheel.ClickDetector

--- Left mouse click (turn on)
clickdetector.MouseClick:connect(function()
   print("lights on")
   for _,p in pairs(workspace.OceanVillagedr201:GetChildren()) do
      if p.Name == ("Downstairs") then
         for _,x in pairs(p:GetChildren()) do
             if x.Name == "Kitchen Bar Counter" then
                 for _,d in pairs(x:GetChildren()) do
                     if d.Name == "barlight" then
                         for _,j in pairs(d:GetChildren()) do
                             if j.Name == "light" then
                                 j.Transparency = 0
                             else
                             end
                         end
                     end
                 end
             end
         end
      end
   end
end)


--- Right mouse click (turn off)
clickdetector.RightMouseClick:connect(function()
  print("lights off")
  for _,p in pairs(workspace.OceanVillagedr201:GetChildren()) do
     if p.Name == "Downstairs" then
         for _,x in pairs(p:GetChildren()) do
             if x.Name == "Kitchen Bar Counter" then
                 for _,d in pairs(x:GetChildren()) do
                     if d.Name == "barlight" then
                         for _,j in pairs(d:GetChildren()) do
                             if j.Name == "light" then
                                 j.Transparency = 1
                             else
                             end
                         end
                     end
                 end
             end
         end
     end
  end
end)
```

This script is responsible for the on and off of a light when the "colorwheel" has detected a click. To keep my workspace organized, I place models into models and then place those models into folders, essentially creating a lot of *.parents* to the original object I want to modify. This leads me to having to call the *:GetChildren()* function, as you can see, so I can get the script to search through all the *parents* for the individual object. Is there a way to simplify this or is this considered the appropriate way of scripting on Roblox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index children of Models the same way you lookup properties on a table. You can use the dot operator for children that don't have spaces in their names, or square brackets for the ones that do.

You can access children of a known path like this :

```
local village = workspace.OceanVillagedr201
local light = village.Downstairs["Kitchen Bar Counter"].barlight.light
light.Transparency = 0
```

Be aware that this approach will throw errors if you have made a mistake in any of the names, or if any of the objects haven't loaded yet.